# How to find the path effecifiently in binary tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming

I am trying to find a path between two nodes.

It could be from the root node to other or just from other to other nodes. The problem I am facing is that the time exceeds when I tested my code. It took really long to find the path.

```
class Node{
      int key; string name; Node* lChild; Node* rChild;
}
```

Here is my pathfinding function.

```
void findPath(string x, string y){ 
      int xKey = findKey(x); // custom function to find the key to move left and right
      int yKey = findKey(y);
      Node* lca = LCA(head, xKey, yKey); // this will find the lca and head node is the just the root node.
      while(true){ // loop through to the left; }
      while(true){ // loop through to the right; }
}
```

After I found the lca, I loop through from left and right. But it took really long since I use two while loops. How do I reduce the time complexity of this finding path?

Here is my Tree photo:
[image: Tree]

Expected output

```
findPath(D, F) --> D, B, A, C, F 

findPath(A, I) --> A, C, G, I

findPath(F, E) --> F, C, A, B, D, E
```

Comment: All your samples include the root node. Your should add a sample which doesn't, e.g. `findPath(J, H)` which should result in `J, I, G, H`. Actually, I would solve your problem exactly like described by you: Find route to first node, find route to second node, but then I would compare the found routes and remove the equal prefix (except the last common parent node).

Comment: Finding a path in a tree is much simpler than finding an optimal path in a directed graph.  That is because only one possible path exists.  All you really need to do is to perform a single depth-first traversal of your graph to locate either one of the nodes.  As soon as you have found a node, you continue searching the graph until you find the other, with the additional task of pushing/popping each node on a stack any time you recurse into/out of a child.  If the search fails at that level, push the node's parent and continue searching. When you find the second node, the stack holds the path.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's a little bit difficult to guess  what you did wrong. As shown in `while(true){ // loop through to the left; }`, this is an infinite loop (and even a broken one). So, there must be something else in your code, and that might be your actual problem.

Comment: @Scheff, the way I described exceeds the time limit.

Comment: To illustrate my suggestion as an example: `findPath(H, D)` might go like this: visit A, visit B, visit D (match), push D, push E, pop E, push B, push A, push C, push F, pop F, push G, push I, push J, pop J, pop I, push H (match).  Now the path is D, B, A, C, G, H and you can simply reverse it if necessary.

Comment: @paddy, thanks for the advice mate. But I am struggling like how will push B, A happen after push E and pop E. Also can you explain you only pop the only part necessary ?

Comment: `int xKey = findKey(x); int yKey = findKey(y);` and then a search afterwards – you are likely traversing the tree multiple times. You should try to traverse the tree not more than once. You could do a depth-first-search until you found both nodes. After discovering the first one you keep protocol of all the further steps (going down left or right or going up from left or right; up left/right: if you need to reconstruct the path in reverse order because of having found end node first).

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah but the input is only string.

Comment: You should work this through on paper.  Think about what you know at each level.  For instance, if the stack is empty, you haven't found either node yet.  If you make your function return a boolean indicating whether the search is complete, then you have everything you need.

Comment: @silncec Well, if input is only string you can construct a tree from, or you have an implicit tree: If you have one root node at index n, you find the its children at indices 2*n + 1 and 2*n + 2. The parent node you find at (n - 1)/2. By index calculations you can traverse the implicit tree exactly as an explicit one.

Comment: If you need to shave off fractions of a second, consider replacing your `string` arguments by references. In extreme cases like this, not copying the string might make the difference. But this only as a side note. Other than that, you could have the algorithm start out as going down the tree unified as long as this is the right path for both values, and only do two separate searches when you have to.

Comment: I decided to knock together a demo using the single traversal method.  My implementation is not particularly optimal but hopefully is clear enough.  See live demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jbb6a66Mn).  Note that this does not require the tree to be ordered in any way.